# How can I use an external JavaScript library in an Angular Library

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, package

I'm developing an Angular library **(Angular 7)** and I need to use an external js file from node_modules in this Library.

- Including it in angular.json or the main project doesn't help --> results in `Can't resolve 'lib-name' in 'my-proj/node_modules/my-lib/fesm5'`
- Including it in scripts in angular.json and using `declare let externalLib: any;` doesn't help --> results in `undefined`
- adding it's type to the `types` array in `tsconfig.lib.json` doesn't help either
- adding it to `peerDependencies` doesn't work as well

The only thing that worked is installing the js file in the main project but that should not be the case.

any ideas?
thank you,

Comment: can you add the line in `angular.json`?

Comment: @benshabatnoam thx for your reply, nope, there's no `scripts` array in angular.json of the library, and adding the line in the scripts array in the angular.json of the main project doesn't help

Comment: @benshabatnoam it's like it's not there, it's not shipped with the library when I publish it and install it to my main project

Comment: I meant, what line did you try to add to your `angular.json` file

Comment: @benshabatnoam oh `"scripts": ["node_modules/lib/dist/lib.min.js"]`

Comment: in minified files (`lib.min.js`) the variable names are differ, maybe this is your problem...

Comment: @benshabatnoam yes I just believe that the module name won't differ, variables maybe yes but not the module name